# Unable to connect to mysql server docker container running in Docker playground

Tags: docker, ssh, ssh-tunnel, dbeaver

I'm running an out of the box mysql docker container inside docker play ground at https://labs.play-with-docker.com/

```sh
[node1] (local) root@192.168.0.8 ~
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS       PORTS                               NAMES
f0f8ae352373   mysql     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago   Up 2 hours   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   memories
[node1] (local) root@192.168.0.8 ~
$
```

Now if I have to connect to this mysql instance from my local machine, it's been suggested to create a SSH tunnel.

This is what I have tried

```sh
➜  sqlconnect ✗ ssh -L 3306:192.168.0.8:3306 ip172-18-0-115-c1mf4d0h550g00dlq95g@direct.labs.play-with-docker.com
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/ankitjha/.ssh/id_rsa':
Connecting to 40.87.120.67:8022
###############################################################
#                          WARNING!!!!                        #
# This is a sandbox environment. Using personal credentials   #
# is HIGHLY! discouraged. Any consequences of doing so are    #
# completely the user's responsibilites.                      #
#                                                             #
# The PWD team.                                               #
###############################################################
[node1] (local) root@192.168.0.8 ~
$
```

When I tried connecting from my sql dbeaver client
[image]

This is the error I got

```sh
[node1] (local) root@192.168.0.8 ~
$ channel 3: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this. It's disabled by design. Check https://github.com/play-with-docker/play-with-docker/issues/373#issuecomment-814553922

If you already have a terminal in the environment, why do you want to connect from your PC?

Comment: I'm teaching docker to an audience familiar with those tools. I want to show them how quickly one can test out different databases with docker.